# CSS grid: minmax with a max value of auto fails to adjust to the height of children

Tags: css

Below is a snippet with a minimum repro case of what I thought, after reading the docs, should work, but doesn't. The snippet contains a grid with three rows: top, middle, and bottom. The height of the middle row of the grid is defined as `minmax(50px, auto)`, which I took to mean "no smaller than 50px, but grow up to the max content height if necessary". The div placed in the middle row has a set height, which is greater than the 50px in the minmax. As you can see by running the snippet, the middle row will overlap with the bottom one. This is because the middle row fails to expand vertically to accommodate the larger height of its content.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(50px, auto) 1fr;
}

.top {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.middle {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.bottom {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

The overlap can be fixed by changing `grid-template-rows: auto minmax(50px, auto) 1fr;` to       `grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;`, like so:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

.top {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.middle {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.bottom {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

but this, of course, will lose the minimum height of the row. Could you please help me understand why the `minmax` setting isn't working as I am expecting it to, and what is the correct way to both ensure the minimum height of the row and to make sure it will grow to fit the height of the children.

Answer (score 0):

Your `minmax()` is working but you defined fixed heights for the grid items `.middle` and `.bottom` and for the grid container `.outer-grid`. If you omit these for the two grid items and define the height for the grid container as `min-height` it's working as expected.

**Working example:**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-grid {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(50px, auto) 1fr;
}

.top {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.middle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.bottom {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="middle">
    middle
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

**Working example:** (the same code like above but with more content in all three grid items)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-grid {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(50px, auto) 1fr;
}

.top {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.middle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.bottom {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="top">
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top<br>
    top top
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle<br>
    middle middle
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom<br>
    bottom bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Umm, but I want the middle row to be able to grow to the height of its content.

Comment: Ok. It wasn't clear because you defined fixed heights. I removed now ```max-height``` and ```overflow``` in my answer...

Comment: It breaks on tall content (see https://jsbin.com/gedejuvuko/edit?html,css,output ; adjust the height of jsbin's viewport so that it's smaller than the height of the text in the bottom row).

Comment: I think the approach I outlined in a sibling answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67690513/3925302) works better (see jsbin example: https://jsbin.com/pujulayuwi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I updated my answer - i forgot the fixed height of the grid container. Now it works - test it...

Answer (score -1):

After playing with my code some more, I think this gets me closer to what I was after: if I change the height of the third row from `1fr` to `minmax(0, 1fr)`, then the middle row will both grow to the full height of its content, and will never be smaller than the minimum value in its minmax function:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer-grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(50px, auto) minmax(0, 1fr);
}

.top {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.middle {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.bottom {
  height: 3600px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outer-grid">
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="middle">middle</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course the problem with this approach is that I can't make sure that the bottom row will always be at least as high as the remainder of the container. All because, [according to the current CSS spec](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2611#issue-317461420), `fr` units can not be used for the minimum value of the `minmax`. Which is a bummer.

Comment: Your code is also not working with taller content. The easiest way to test it: copy the html from the second stack snippet of my updated answer and paste it in your stack snippet...